# Finding an $n$ such that $x^{n}<y$ for $x\in \mathbb R:|x-\frac{1}{2}|<\frac{1}{2}$, and $y\in \mathbb Z:y>0$.

Tags: real-analysis

let $(x,y)$ be such that $0<x<1$ and $y>0$. Your goal is to find such $n$ that $x^n<y$

Comment: What is your question and maybe you fix your title

Comment: your title says proving.......what?

Comment: Maybe you have a look to this answer it might not be fully satisfactory since I dont really understand what intend to prove

Comment: In The Title you have the union instead of intersection or I am just misunderstanding you again

Comment: I think you mean $(1,y)$ instead of $(0,y)$; for example $(0,1)$ isn't in any of the sets $T_n$.

Comment: does the answer below answer solved your problem . then I can therefore give a better edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<x<1$ and $y>0$, then $$x<1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x} >1$$ and we can find an $a\in \mathbb R>0$ such that $$\frac{1}{x}=1+a$$ holds. From Bernoulli's inequality we get that $$\frac{1}{x}^{n}\ge 1+na, \forall n\in \mathbb N.$$ Thus we get $$x^{n}\le \frac{1}{1+na}.$$ Now let $n$ be such that $\frac{1}{1+na}<y$.Then, $$x^{n}\le \frac{1}{1+na}< y.$$ QED

Comment: As simple as it gets. This proves that $x^{n} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty $. +1

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y$, $0<x<1$ $y>0$

- If $x\le y $ then take $n = 2,3,4....$ since $$.....<x^3<x^2<x\le y$$
- if $x>y$ then 
  $$A=\{p\in\Bbb N:x^p>y\}\neq\emptyset$$
  is none empty and bounded subset of $\Bbb N$ then has a maximum.
  indeed,
  $1\in A$ and $$1>x>x^p>y >0\implies p\ln x>\ln y\implies 0< p< \frac{\ln y}{\ln x}$$

whrere this $ p\ln x>\ln y\implies 0< p< \frac{\ln y}{\ln x}$

holds true because $\ln x<0$ ,
$$\ln a<0~~~if~~0<a<1$$

Now let $$j=\max A\implies j\in A~~~and ~~j+1\not\in A$$ that is $$x^j>y\ge x^{j+1}>x^{j+2}$$ 
Then taking $n=j+2$ yields $x^n<y$

> In each case there always exists $n$ such that $x^n<y$

**Now Let Prove that**

$$\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}^{\infty} T_{n} =\{(x,0)\in \mathbb R^{2}:0\le x\le 1\}\cup\{(1,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}:0\le y\le 1\}:=T  $$

where $T_{n}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}:0\le x\le 1,0\le y\le x^{n}\}$

1. let $(x,y)\in\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}^{\infty} T_{n}$

then $$0\le y\le x^n~~~\forall ~~n\in\Bbb N \implies0\le y\le \lim_{n\to \infty}x^n = \begin{cases}0&if ~~~~0\le x<1\\
1&if~~x=1\end{cases}$$

Hence $y= 0$ if $x\neq 1$ i.e $(x,y)= (x,0) \in T$ and $0\le y\le  1$ if $x= 1$ i.e $(x,y)= (1,y)\in T.$
Then we have $$\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}^{\infty} T_{n}  \subset T$$

2. The fact that,

$$\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}^{\infty} T_{n}  \supset T$$
is trivial since $y= 0$ implies $y \le x^n$ and  if $x = 1$ implies 
$0\le y\le 1^n$.

Comment: See the full answer now . Can you tell me What is Bernoulli inequality?

Comment: you are right I fixed it

Comment: The goal of the OP is to prove that T is the intersection of $T^n$ that is why

Comment: In the above prove prove do you see where such inequality is needed? I don't. Moreover The OP says this answer was OK. In fact following this proof no inequality is needed